# Angular 7 unit test with window.location.href

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do unit test for my API request to check whether it returns the expected result. In the callback of API request, I have to redirect the page to an external url using window.location.href. 
Seems the test case trying to redirect the page and headless chrome returns disconnected error. I tried to create mock window service but still not working.

````
 this.apiSvc.logout().subscribe((res) => {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.location.href = res.url;
    })```

App.component.spec.ts

 it('should redirect to external page on clicking of logout function', async(() => { 
    spyOn(apiSvc, 'logout').and.callFake(() => {
      return of({url: mockWindow.location.href})
    })
    component.onLogout();
    expect(uiApiSvc.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

Error message
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 7 of 26 DISCONNECTED (30.567 secs / 0.722 secs)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you need to test everything except the actual setting of window.location.href - you can trust the browser to do this correctly. I would wrap that part in a function and check that the function itself is called with the correct value:

```
public navigateToResponseUrl(url: string): void {
   window.location.href = url;
}
```

Spec file:

```
const navigateToResponseUrlSpy = spyOn(apiSvc, 'navigateToResponseUrl');
...
expect(navigateToResponseUrlSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/your/url');
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way yesterday and it was working.However wanted to know, is there any way I can do the unit test on widow.location by mocking window object?