# Angular How to test window.location.href with jasmine, karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In Angular project (Angular CLI: 9.1.4) I have a component with has function using `window.location.href = EXTERNAL_URL`

a.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from 'services/service';

@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  redirect() {
    window.location.href = 'https://sample.com'
  }
}
```

For unit test, I have a.component.spec.ts

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AComponent } from './A.component';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('#AComponent', () => {
  let component: AComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [AComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  describe('test', () => {
    it('test redirect function', () => {
      component.redirect();

      expect(window.location.href).toEqual('https://sample.com');
    });
  });
});
```

it must check the URL  'window.location.href' is same as I expected.

But when running test, showed error which says

> Expected 'http://localhost:0987/context.html' to equal 'https://sample.com'

Why window.location.href param is like this?

Also, Karma (v5.0.4) showed test result on browser normally, but on this test, browser page is suddenly changed.

[image]

It happens because 'window.location.href' had run on test browser( it tried to open https://sample.com). But because of this redirection, I cannot see Karma result.

So, my question is

- How can I test window.location.href
- How can I stop redirection on karma test browser

P.S. I had thought that using window.location.href was not good, but I couldn't find any ways to redirect external URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 7 unit test with window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626721/angular-7-unit-test-with-window-location-href)

Comment: @Roy it says `need to test everything except the actual setting of window.location.href -` . Maybe I don't need to test `window.location.href` itself. I'll remove this test( still, I wonder if I could solve the second question; stop redirection ...). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here the biggest problem is in the window object itself. But we can redefine it for the test environment. My solution:

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'a',
      templateUrl: './a.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
    })
    export class AComponent {
      private window = window;

      constructor() {}

      redirect() {
        this.window.location.href = 'https://sample.com'
      }
    }
```

spec:

```js
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    
    import { AComponent } from './A.component';
    import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    describe('#AComponent', () => {
      let component: AComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<AComponent>;
    
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [HttpClientModule],
          declarations: [AComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
      }));
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      describe('test', () => {
        it('test redirect function', () => {
          let currentLocation;
          component['window'] = {
            location: {
             set href(value) { currentLocation = value;}
            }
          } as Window & typeof globalThis;

          component.redirect();
    
          expect(currentLocation).toBe('https://sample.com');
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is to use an `InjectionToken` to provide the window-object.

See this [blog post](https://medium.com/@abampakos/a-better-angular-window-b20da0e02dd7) for more details on this approach for the window object.

### Naive approach

Roughly it can achieved as:

```js
// variable in component class
private window: (Window & typeof globalThis) | null

// component constructor 
constructor(
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
) {
  this.window = this.document.defaultView
}

// redirection in component function
this.window?.location.assign('https://sample.com')

// in unit test
it('test redirect function', () => {
  let currentLocation;
  component['window'] = {
    location: {
      set href(value) { currentLocation = value;}
    }
  } as Window & typeof globalThis;

  component.redirect();
    
  expect(currentLocation).toBe('https://sample.com');
}
```

Note that the test is quite similar to the other answer. Though by using an `InjectionToken` it has the major benefit that it does not depend on the browser being the running environment.

You could also directly use `this.document.defaultView` instead of assigning `this.window` though. It depends on your taste.

### Cleaner approach

It's better to define external navigation as a service and provide the window as a token for window because this allows the most efficient stubbing.

```js
// The navigation service
export class ExternalNavigationService {
  private API_HOST = 'example.com'
  private DASHBOARD_URL = `${this.API_HOST}/dashboard`

  constructor(
    @Inject(WINDOW) public window: Window & typeof globalThis,
  ) { }

  toDashboard(){
    this.navigate(this.DASHBOARD_URL)
  }

  private navigate(url: string | URL){
    this.window.location.assign(url)
  }
}
```

```js
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>('Global window object', {
  factory: () => window
});
```

```js
// Unit tests for the navigation sevice 
describe('ExternalNavigationService', () => {
  let externalNavigationService: ExternalNavigationService
  let windowStub: Window & typeof globalThis

  beforeEach(() => {
    windowStub = {
      location: { assign(value: string) { return value }},
    } as unknown as Window & typeof globalThis

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ { provide: WINDOW, useValue: windowStub } ]
    })
    externalNavigationService = TestBed.inject(ExternalNavigationService)
  })

  describe('#navigate', () => {
    it('redirects to the given url', () => {
      spyOn(windowStub.location, 'assign')
      externalNavigationService['navigate']('/test')
      expect(windowStub.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/test')
    })
  })

  describe('#toDashboard', () => {
    it('navigates to the dashboard', () => {
      spyOn(externalNavigationService, <never>'navigate')
      externalNavigationService.toDashboard()
      expect(externalNavigationService['navigate']).toHaveBeenCalledWith('example.com/dashboard')
    })
  })
})
```

Now you can mock the `ExternalNavigationService` anywhere and just test that itself calls the required navigation method:

```js
expect(mockedExternalNavigationService.toDashboard).toHaveBeenCalled()
```